# Spring: Publishing event from InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSet method does NOT work

Tags: spring, events

Recently I have found that when I publish an event from org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet(), then it is unable to publish that event!

However this very same event trigger gets invoked if I invoke it from @Controller or any other class class (the event invocation mechanism remains same for both places).

I have put a print statement after publishing event in InitBean ('Trigger done') and that is successfully printed too.

If you have any idea about this behaviour then please let me know.

Thanks very much

```
//Sample code for InitializingBean:
@Component 
public class InitBean implements InitializingBean {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public InitBean(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new TriggerEvent());
        System.out.println("Trigger done");
    }
}

// Sample code for trigger event:
public class TriggerEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    public TriggerEvent() {
        super("source");
    }
}

// Sample code for listener:
@Component 
public class TriggerListener {
    @EventListener(TriggerEvent.class)
    public void trigger(TriggerEvent triggerEvent) {
        System.out.println("Trigger event has come");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, I think the problem is that `afterPropertiesSet` is just too early in the Spring Bean live cycle.

Try firing the event a little later.
Rather in a `@PostConstruct`, an init-method, or when the application context refresh event was catched.

`@PostConstruct`:

```
@Component 
public class InitBean {
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void fire() throws Exception {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new TriggerEvent());
        System.out.println("Trigger done");
    }
}
```

init-method:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(initMethod="fire")
    public InitBean initBean (ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        return new InitBean (publisher);
    }
}

public class InitBean {
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void fire() throws Exception {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new TriggerEvent());
        System.out.println("Trigger done");
    }
}
```

context refresh way

```
@Component 
public class InitBean {
...
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        fire();
    }

    public void fire() throws Exception {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new TriggerEvent());
        System.out.println("Trigger done");
    }
}
```

I don't know if the first two approaches solve the suspected problem, but the last one should work.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I have tried with the last one first, as that looks a sure shot way to go and it is working fine.